# Stochastic resonance

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am trying to look for a stochastic resonance in a system described by Langevin equation and a periodic forcing. While I can simulate an SDE numerically I have no idea how to calculate the 'signal to noise
ratio' which quantifies the stochastic resonance. I use python for my computations. Thank you very much in advance.

The equation is of the form
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-U'(x)+Acos \Omega t+\xi(t)$$

Comment: can you provide more details? is this a model from a paper? What is $U'$? Is the model supposed to be nonlinear?

Comment: See also:  R Benzi et al 1981 J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 14 L453 "The mechanism of stochastic resonance": they invoke some kind of nonlinearity: $U'(x)=-x(a -x^2)$. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/14/11/006/meta